# "serviceworker" must be a dictionary in your web app manifest

Tags: node.js, reactjs, razorpay

I am trying to integrate Razorpay subscriptions.

I am using NodeJs as Backend and React for Frontend.

Manifest.json looks like this -

```
{
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Create React App Sample",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff",
}
```

The error comes up whenever I click pay button, and I guess due to this Razorpay is not considering the order as Subscription.

Update :
I raised a query on Razorpay portal and received the following reply.

[image: Mail basically says to ignore the warning.]

Comment: welcome to SO! Please, show us a piece of code with what you have tried so far